# Extracting maximum numbers from file names

Tags: bash, sorting

I'm new to bash and wondered if you guys could help - I have a list of files named things like
amp1_X_1
amp1_X_2
...
amp43_X_3
and have to extract the maximum values of the numbers which appear either side of *X*.
I've been looking at various links to help solve my problem, but when I try and tweak the examples to suit my purpose I get various errors, like "command not found" or %% operators remaining unevaluated.
[How do I Select Highest Number From Series of <string>_# File Names in Bash Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579430/how-do-i-select-highest-number-from-series-of-string-file-names-in-bash-scri)
[extract numbers from file names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10432150/extract-numbers-from-file-names)

For example, I tried something like

```
max=-1
for file in amp*_X_1
do
  pattern=_X_*
  num=${file}%%${pattern}
  num=${num}##amp
  echo "num is $num"
  [[ $num -gt $max ]] && max=$num    
done
echo "max is: $max"
```

(credit largely to ghostdog74 in the first link) which would in any case only work for one set of numbers, but it returns with the %% unevaluated. Have I missed something stupid/is there a better way to do this?
Thanks!

Comment: You've got the syntax wrong: `${file%%$pattern}`, `${num##amp}`

Answer (score 0):

there are some errors in your script:

1)`for file in amp*_X_1`

if you want use the files in a specific folder you have to use commands like `ls` or `find`
i.e.

```
for file in $(ls -1 <your file>)
for file in ($find . -name "<your file>")
```

etc..

2) `num=${file}%%${pattern}`

use `num=${file%%$pattern}`

below you can find your script edited:

```
max=-1
for file in $(find . -name "amp*")
do
  echo "file[$file]"
  pattern=_X_*
  num=${file%%$pattern} 
  num=$(echo $num|sed "s/^\.\///g" | sed "s/amp//g")
  echo "num is $num"
  [[ $num -gt $max ]] && max=$num    
done
echo "max is: $max"
```

output:

```
sh-4.3$ bash -f main.sh                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
file[./amp1_X_1]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
num is 1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
file[./amp3_X_2]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
num is 3                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
file[./amp3_X_1]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
num is 3                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
file[./amp43_X_1]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
num is 43                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
max is: 43
```

now this script is looking for the maximum between the numbers on the left side of X.
From your question isn't clear what's your expected result.. 
1) find maximum between all numbers on both X side?
2) find maximum between all numbers on left X side?
3) find maximum between all numbers on right X side?

if 1 is the case you have to add another variable, get the value, and check it.

something like

```
   max=-1
for file in $(find . -name "amp*")
do
  echo "file[$file]"
  pattern=_X_*

  num=${file%%$pattern} 
  num=$(echo $num|sed "s/^\.\///g" | sed "s/amp//g")
  echo "num is $num"

  pattern2=*_X_
  num2=${file##$pattern2} 
  echo "num2 is $num2"  


  [[ $num -gt $max ]] && max1=$num    
  [[ $num2 -gt $max ]] && max2=$num2
  if [[ $max1 -gt $max2 ]]; then
        echo "max is: $max1" 
  else
        echo "max is: $max2"
  fi

done
#echo "max is: $max"
```